# Is TrimApp specific for Samsung phones or present on all 4.x Android Phones?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, video

I'm confused regarding the Trim Video application. On my Galaxy Note it can be launched from the Gallery when I play a video and chose Trim from the menu.
I would like to know if this Trim application is available on all the Android 4.x phones or only specific to Samsung?

Comment: Can you edit to include the source of where the app came from?

Comment: It comes with my Samsung Galaxy Note, I haven't installed it from any external source. I would like to know if the same comes with non-Samsung 4.x phones.

Comment: There are a couple of [video trimmers in the playstore](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=video-trim&c=apps) in case you need one on another device.

Comment: No, I just would like to know if a stock Android 4.x firmware comes with any vdeo trimmer. Unfortunately I only have 2 Samsung devices, don't have anything else.

Comment: More than likely, the Trim Video application is part of the Samsung Galaxy Note ROM, so its proprietary and confined to Samsung only. :)

Comment: @t0mm13b I guess that's the answer then, I can accept it then if you put it as the answer.

Comment: There's certainly no such app on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: @Alex - Trim video is also present on my Galaxy S3 on 4.1 JB.